# Identifying each row uniquely for using in forms using jsp in struts

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts2, row

I new to struts and JSP. I'm doing an application which displays the rows fetched from database. I want to consider each row as a form and when submitted (using a button in the last column) that button should submit some identity (probably the primary key whose value i have in value stack) to the handler action class. How can I implement this functionality using the S tags?

Comment: Can you provide your code and include a list of solutions you've already tried?

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and its working. <s:textfield type="hidden" name="status" value="%{status}" />

Answer (score 1):

Make the ID of the button id="button_" so when the button is clicked you can pull the value off the button.

Alternatively you can use a hidden text input field in the row that stores the value you want to send when the button is clicked, and when the button is clicked, you pull the value of the text field using a similar method of the above.